# Excel Sort a column based on the number after last -

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet with a column like

```
regno
KEK-123
KE1-122
KL-02-D-211
KL-02-F-7232
KL-03-M-6232
KL-04-P-4917
KL-11-R-7232
KL-12-811
KL-12-B-3223
```

I need to sort this column based on the numbers after the last -. Can excel sort do that? I though of removing all the contents before last -. But dont know how to do that also. Please guide me how to do that.

Comment: Will it ever be over 4 digits on the left side of that? like 10000

Comment: @Moacir left of what?

Comment: Ooops. I always mix my left and right. I meant right, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a helper column to sort the data.
Put the following function into the cell B2, and drag down:

```
=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("£";SUBSTITUTE(A2;"-";"£";LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"-";"")))))
```

If your Excel uses commas instead of semicolons just replace them.

So then it is this:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("£",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","£",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")))))"
```